# Upload Data onto Shiny App dynamically

Tags: r, shiny

I am wondering if it is possible to let user upload data (may be in .CSV format) in a Shiny app from their local Hard disk while using the App, then Shiny would perform analysis dynamically.

Currently, for such analysis, I keep data in RData/CSV format in `WWW` folder, and then Shiny takes data from there - however this is not really dynamic.

Any such idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the file input widget: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Shiny has an input called a `fileInput` that lets users upload data. From the documentation [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html):

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        accept = c(
          "text/csv",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv")
        ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this serves my purpose. One quick question : Is there any option to control the statement 'Upload complete' after uploading the file. I would rather prefer not to have any such statement. Thanks,

Comment: The 'Upload complete' message is not customizable, but if you wanted to you could hide the whole upload bar with css, or look into shinyjs if you want to keep the upload bar but change the message.